# PYTHON - como usar um laço sem parar o Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Tenho esse programa que é uma especie de 'ForçaBruta'(automatizei um processo de clica num lugar, digitar um numero, e clica em outro lugar com @Pyautogui), 
preciso usar um laço porem quando o laço inicia o Tkinter para, assim não consegui pensar em como fazer algo para pausar o 'laço'! o codigo:

```
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui
import time

class ForceBrute:
    def __init__(self,master=None):
#faz com que a janela não possa ser redimensionada pelo usuario
        master.resizable(width=False,height=False)

#Containers para os itens da interface
        self.con1 = Frame(master)
        self.con1['pady'] = 8
        self.con1.pack()

        self.con2 = Frame(master)
        self.con2['pady'] = 15
        self.con2.pack()


        self.con3 = Frame(master)
        self.con3['pady'] = 30
        self.con3.pack()


        self.con4 = Frame(master)
        self.con4['pady'] = 10
        self.con4.pack()


#itens da interface
        self.tTitle = Label(self.con1)
        self.tTitle['font'] = ('Roboto','30')
        self.tTitle['text'] = 'SiriusForce'
        self.tTitle.pack()

#recebe o valor de aparti de quando deve iniciar
        self.eDe = Entry(self.con2,justify = 'center',relief=RIDGE,width=3)
        self.eDe['font'] = ('Roboto', '20')
        self.eDe.pack(side=LEFT)
#coloca 100 no campo como padrão
        self.eDe.insert(0,'100')

        self.tAte = Label(self.con2)
        self.tAte['font'] = ('Roboto', '20')
        self.tAte['text'] = 'Ate:'
        self.tAte.pack(side=LEFT)

#recebe ate que valor deve ir
        self.eAte = Entry(self.con2,justify = 'center',relief=RIDGE,width=3)
        self.eAte['font'] = ('Roboto', '20')
        self.eAte.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.eAte.insert(0,'999')

#botão para iniciar 
        self.bIniciar = Button(self.con3,relief=RIDGE,fg='blue')
        self.bIniciar['font'] =('Roboto', '25')
        self.bIniciar['text'] = 'Iniciar'
        self.bIniciar['command'] = self.iniciar
        self.bIniciar.pack(side=LEFT)


        self.bPausar = Button(self.con3,relief=RIDGE,fg='red')
        self.bPausar['font'] =('Roboto', '25')
        self.bPausar['text'] = 'Pausar'
#      self.bPausar['command'] =           seria para pausar o 'laço' 
        self.bPausar.pack(side=LEFT)


#exibe em que numero parou
        self.eCont = Entry(self.con4,justify= 'center',relief=RIDGE,width=3,bg='black',fg='green')
        self.eCont['font'] = ('Roboto', '30')
        self.eCont.pack()




        self.cod = 0


    def iniciar(self):
        self.de = int(self.eDe.get()) -1 
        self.ate = int(self.eAte.get()) 

        print('Iniciado De:',self.de,'Ate:',self.ate) # só para visualizar 

        self.cod = self.de

        while(self.cod < self.ate):

            self.cod +=1

            pyautogui.doubleClick(697,363)
            pyautogui.typewrite(str(self.cod))

            print(self.cod)

            self.eCont.delete(0,END)
            self.eCont.insert(0,self.cod)

            pyautogui.click(880,516)

            time.sleep(1.5)


root = Tk()
root.geometry('220x350+400+100')
root.title('Generico')
root.attributes('-topmost',True)
ForceBrute(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Já vi em alguns lugares que posso usar o 'root.after()' porem não consegui implementar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O programa roda em uma thread só - então ou ele executa o loop do tkinter, responsável por receber e executar eventos do mouse, teclado, etc... ou fica no seu `while...time.sleep(1.5)`.

Esse tipo de programa (gráfico) sempre tem que se basear em responder a eventos: o que fica rodando o tempo todo é o loop de eventos - no caso do tkinter, o que é ativado pelo `mainloop`. Os trechos de código que escrevemos tem que executar uma tarefa, e devolver o processamento para o loop principal (também vale para código Javascript embutido em páginas web, por exemplo).

O que tem que ser feito então é, junto com o processamento do seu código, agendar um evento para chamar a função de novo. Esse evento de agendamento é o que é feito com a chamada ao método `.after(intervalo, objeto chamável)`

Esse evento chamável vai rodar o seu código que tem que ser repetido uma única vez, e agendar sua próxima chamada - e não criar um while. No caso do seu código, o mais propício é colocar o corpo do seu while como um método separado, que será chamado diretamente pelo tkinter, com o uso do `.after`:

```
class ForceBrute:
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        # Guarda uma referência ao root:
        self.master = master
        #faz com que a janela não possa ser redimensionada pelo usuario
        master.resizable(width=False,height=False)
        ...

    ...

    def iniciar(self):
        self.de = int(self.eDe.get()) -1 
        self.ate = int(self.eAte.get()) 

        print('Iniciado De:',self.de,'Ate:',self.ate) # só para visualizar 

        self.cod = self.de
        self.verifica()

    def verifica(self):

        self.cod +=1

        pyautogui.doubleClick(697,363)
        pyautogui.typewrite(str(self.cod))

        print(self.cod)

        self.eCont.delete(0,END)
        self.eCont.insert(0,self.cod)

        pyautogui.click(880,516)

        if (self.cod < self.ate):
            self.master.after(1500, self.verifica)
```

Então  - a única outra coisa que foi necessária aí foi guardar uma referência à janela do programa dentro da classe - por que é lá que está o método `.after`.

E o outro detalhe importante: ao se chamar esse tipo de método em que se passa uma função para ser chamada de volta (callback), nunca se colocam os parenteses depois do nome da função ou método. Isso faria a função ser executada ali, e seu resultado de retorno ser mandado como um parâmetro para o `after`. Sem os parenteses, funções e métodos são tratados como qualquer outra variável pelo Python.

(e, 1500 é só o seu 1.5 segundo reescrito em milissegundos)

Comment: Eu tive um estranhamento inicial por usar diretamente `self.after`. Então fui ver que nos meus projetos de brincadeira eu sempre herdo de `tk.Frame`, então essa herança faria a parte do campo `self.master` de sua solução. Muito boa a resposta

Comment: Isso - em particular, eu considero _não_ herdar de tk.Frame um grande avanço - não sei por que os tutoriais continuam recomendando isso: é um anti-pattern bem conhecido (sua classe fica com centenas de atributos e métodos que não tem nenhuma relação com a lógica da sua aplicação. Manter uma referência ao root em um atributo qualquer (no caso self.master) resolve isso.

Comment: Mais uma vez Jsbueno salvando o dia kkkk! resolveu meu problema, obrigado! :3